# Alternatives to pandas to datetime for large dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a 70M rows `dataframe`. There is a string field of timestamps. I want to convert them to `datetime[ns]`. Trying with `pd.to_datetime` results in 15+ minutes of wait and eventually I have to hit `CTRL+C`.

I looked up various approaches to this in previous questions and have tried a bunch of them:

```
df
timestamp                close
2021-07-01 13:00:00.10   188880
2021-07-01 13:00:00.15   188880
2021-07-01 13:00:00.18   188880
2021-07-01 13:00:00.20   188880
2021-07-01 13:00:01.10   188880
2021-07-01 13:00:04.10   188880
```

Approaches I have tried so far:

```
# 1st
pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f)

#2nd
pd.Timestamp(df['timestamp'])
# gave me an error, which seemed to imply I need to go .apply route

#3rd
df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))
# Again way too slow
```

I am on a Mac M1 with 8 GB RAM.

Is this a system/memory problem?

Comment: I think it has to do with the overall DataFrame size. Have you heard about Dask and Vaex? Both set pandas to run in parallel and might help.

Comment: @YannisP. I think you are right, I have an old script and didn't want to rework it. I guess I either fire up a AWS instance with higher memory or try reworking the script with dask. Thanks

Comment: not having the actual data but only a dummy Series of 70M entries as specified in the question (date/time string), I get a `%timeit` of 9.2s for `pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)` on my machine. So I'd also suspect the bottle neck to be somewhere else.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: In particular, please refrain from adding "thanks", "TIA" and other chatty devices in your posts ([see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)). We don't have enough editors to clean up the number of posts we get every day. Editors are volunteers, have mercy on us.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jupyter notebook you should consider that Jupyter notebook has a default memory limit size.